# How to process a drop-down (<select>) menu in a .php file?

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a splitted "landing page":

As you can see there are 2 differents contact-forms. What I want to do is to insert into the "recived mail" (the one from the .php file) the choice from the "drop-down" menu. Basically I want to process that choice, because into the "recived-mail" I can only see information about Name, Email and the message.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php">
   <select>
      <option value="1">Bitte rufen Sie mich an zur Kontaktaufnahme</option>
      <option value="2">Ich wünsche eine Rohbaubesichtigung</option>
      <option value="3">Ich wünsche eine Präsentation über AQUILA bei mir im Hause</option>
      <option value="4">Bitte senden Sie mir die umfassende Broschüre</option>
      <option value="5">Bitte mailen Sie mir detailliertere Unterlagen über AQUILA</option>
   </select>
   <p>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name und Vorname">
   </p>
   <p>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail"> <br>
   </p>
   <p>
      <input type="text" name="betreff" placeholder="Betreff"> <br>
   </p>
   <p>
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="Nachricht"></textarea>
   </p>
   <input type="submit" value="Senden"><br>
</form>
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php">
   <select>
      <option value="5">Bitte senden Sie mir die umfassende Broschüre</option>
      <option value="6">Bitte mailen Sie mir detailliertere Unterlagen über das Wohnen im AQUILA</option>
   </select>
   <p>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name und Vorname">
   </p>
   <p>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail"> <br>
   </p>
   <p>
      <input type="text" name="betreff" placeholder="Betreff"> <br>
   </p>
   <p>
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="Nachricht"></textarea>
   </p>
   <input type="submit" value="Senden"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: There is no `name` attribute for `select`s.

Comment: So just add a name="" and then? @b0s3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give select a name:

```
<select name="xyz">
```

Comment: Ok, done... and now?  i've to add it here?

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message'];

Comment: @AntonioCasarano You will get the value like other input field as $xyz = $_POST['xyz'];. But you should know that,  you will receive the date of value attribute [1,2 etc.], not the text in between option tag.

Comment: Ok, i got... now it works... i'm not so good in php but now it's okay. Thanks guyz. I love this community :)

Comment: @AntonioCasarano you are welcome. If this answer helps you, you can accept this answer.

Comment: i think that i need more reputation to do this right?

Comment: To accept an answer you don't need more reputation. You can just tick this answer. And to up vote an answer you need at least 15 reputation.